# How can we Integrate Xamarin.Forms Application/Component with Xamarin native Application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I have developed an app/component using Xamarin.Forms and as per the requirement I need to integrate that component with another app which is developed on Xamarin Native in Android as well as iOS.
Kindly help me with the suggestions or references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen something like that on a sample called [Native2Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms).
What it does, at least in Android, is to use a separete activity to integrate the Xamarin Forms PCL (FormsActivity).